# JComboBox populetd with my object

Tags: java, swing

I have a class called persone (peoples), it's just an arraylist of object persona (person).
I want to use this the object persone for  populate a `JComboBox`.
I've read many post, and I've understood that I've to use `DefaultComboBoxModel(E[] items)`, but, of course, I've missed something.   I made some mistake. Can I have an example ? And how to set or get the selected item?

This is my class:

```
public class Persone {

    private  ArrayList<Persona> el = new ArrayList<Persona>();
        public Persone() {
    }

    public ArrayList<Persona> getEl() {
        return el;
    }

    public void setEl(ArrayList<Persona> el) {
        this.el = el;
    }

    public boolean delPersonaFromPersone(Persona persona) {
        return this.el.remove(persona);
    }

    public boolean addPersonaToPersone(Persona persona) {
        return this.el.add(persona);
    }

    public boolean substPersonaInPersone(Persona persona, Persona withPersona ) {
        if ( !this.el.remove(persona))
            return false;

        return this.el.add(persona);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Persone [el=" + el + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add an Object containing an ArrayList to a combo box.

Instead you need to add individual `Persona` object to the combo box.

Then you would need to provide a custom renderer to display the `Persona` object.

Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information and examples on how to do this.

Comment: Ok, I can't add an ArrayList, but I can convert it to an array and use it?

Comment: @FabrizioRestori, I guess you could use the ArrayList.toArray(...) method.  Or, you could write looping code to copy each item from the ArrayList to the combo box directly.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my mistake (some bad assignment).
For use in `JComboBox`, I've made a new array from ArrayList. 
Here my code:

```
JComboBox<Persona> cbResponsabile = new JComboBox<Persona>();

Persona[] array = persone.getEl().toArray(new Persona[persone.getEl().size()]);

cbResponsabile.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(array));
contentPanel.add(cbResponsabile);

// .....
// assignment
// persona is an element of array
cbResponsabile.setSelectedItem(persona);
```